# What is the best way to pass a DataTable into a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to pass a DataTable into a stored procedure in MS SQL 2008 to insert multiple rows into a table at the same time. I have come across methods that use XML documents for this and even passing lists as image data.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Give code samples and/or references if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) and [SQL Server 2008: Table Valued Parameters](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Table-Valued Parameters are a good option, personally I prefer to create a temp table in the calling stored procedure and read from the temp table in the called procedure.

So in code that would be:

```
CREATE PROC DoStuff
AS BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tobeinserted (Data1 INT, Data2 INT...)
    EXEC InsertRows
END

CREATE PROC InsertRows
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM #tobeinserted
END
```

This works reliably, because temporary tables have a lifetime until the stored procedure in which they are created exits. An advantage to this method is that temporary tables, unlike table valued parameters, can have (clustered) indexes defined, so lookups in these tables can be very fast. A disadvantage is that you cannot run two instances of the SP simultaneously.